# How to have a working SplitViewController within a tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have been researching and researching and trying everything i could find on the internet but nothing seems to work for me. Can anyone tell me how to have a splitview controller as a child view of a tabbar controller? the closest ive gotten to getting it right is when i click on the tab it shows the detail view instead of the master. if some one could give me a clean cut way to achieve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the code you have so far?

Comment: I Posted this also and didnt really get help but it is what i have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277908/uisplitviewcontroller-within-uitabbarcontroller-swift

Answer (score 1):

[Answers here might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633532/navigate-to-a-splitviewcontroller) apple recommends UISplitViewController should always be the rootviewcontroller

Here is the note from apple

> You cannot push a split view controller onto a navigation stack. Although it is possible to install a split view controller as a child in some other container view controllers, doing is not recommended in most cases. Split view controllers are normally installed at the root of your app’s window.

I recommend you to create your customn splitViewController

Comment: ive created my own custom splitviewcontroller class and put the code in this example in it and it didnt work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277908/uisplitviewcontroller-within-uitabbarcontroller-swift 
what should i put in the custom class?

Comment: I didnt mean creating a customn `UISplitViewController` I meant create yout own splitview using viewcontrollers like https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

Comment: In the example you mentioned `UITabBarController` is the rootViewController but u need to have your `UISplitViewController` as the rootViewController

Comment: ill check out the first comment, but to your second comment. is there a way to have the splitviewcontroller as rootview and my app still be able to navigate with a tabbarcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Start with just a `splitViewController` and try to get that one working, see for instance this excellent [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/building-rss-reader-using-uisplitviewcontroller-uipopoverviewcontroller/).  Once your happy with that, try to embed it inside a `tabBarController`, either in code or in a storyboard. Follow the tutorial carefully, you will need to make some adjustments when you add the `tabBarController`.  Good luck!